# Regex is not validating date correctly

Tags: python, regex, validation, tkinter

```
 def chkDay(x, size, part):
     dayre = re.compile('[0-3][0-9]') # day digit 0-9
     if (dayre.match(x)):
         if (len(x) > size):
             return tkMessageBox.showerror("Warning", "This "+ part +" is invalid")
             app.destroy
         else:
             tkMessageBox.showinfo("OK", "Thanks for inserting a valid "+ part)
     else:
         tkMessageBox.showerror("Warning", part + " not entered correctly!")
         root.destroy

#when clicked
chkDay(vDay.get(),31, "Day")

#interface of tkinter
vDay = StringVar()
Entry(root, textvariable=vDay).pack()
```

Problem:

- Not validating, I can put in a day greater than 31 and it still shows: OK
- root (application) does not close when I call *root.destroy*

Comment: How do I stop the tk application by using code?

Comment: `if x.isdigit() and int(x) <= size: print 'yup, correct input.'`

Comment: In your code where you use `len` are you sure you didn't mean to put `int`?  `len('99')` is 2 which is less than 31, so it would pass your test.

Comment: `root.destroy` should be `root.destroy()`.  Without the parenthesis, you are not calling the method.

Comment: You have `app.destroy` and `root.destroy`, both lacking parenthesis.  But which is it `app` or `root`?

Comment: Oh I see now thanks. app and root were 2 different tk applications.

Answer (score 5):

Validating date with regex is hard. You can use some patterns from: http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=4&categoryId=5&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

or from http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/226-how-to-validate-traditional-date-formats-with-regular-expressions/

Remember that it is especially hard to check if year is leap, for example is date 2011-02-29 valid or not?

I think it is better to use specialized functions to parse and validate date. You can use `strptime()` from `datetime` module.

Comment: +1 : regular expressions are incredibly handy, but not for everything. Use the `datetime` module instead.

Answer (score 2):

Let the standard `datetime` library handle your datetime data as well as parsing:

```
import datetime

try:
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%d')
except ValueError:
    # insert error handling
else:
    # date_string is ok, it represents the date stored in dt, now use it
```

Answer (score 1):

31 is actually in your regex because `[0-3][0-9]` is not exactly what you're looking for.
You would better try to cast it to a int and explicitly check its bound.
Else the correct regex would be `([0-2]?\d|3[01])` to match a number from 0 up to 31

Comment: I want to use a regex so that the user cannot enter letters, only numbers.

Comment: Taking care of that automatically happens when you attempt to cast to integer; if there are letters, that will raise a `ValueError` (since the input isn't interpretable as an integer) which you can then handle.

Comment: Or if you want to avoid catching a `ValueError` just do `if not x.isdigit() or int(x) > size: print 'bad input!'`

Answer (score 0):

In order to limit the values between 1 and 31, you could use:

```
[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]
```